# Java thread to trigger at multiple timers

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

I want to create some sort of alarm clock with multiple alarms (timings) that counts time and notifies me when on different timings:

```
private List<SomeTime> timings; //can also be just the seconds to count

public void run() {
    while(counting) {
        //if any of the timings is reached do something
        for (SomeTime time : timings) {
            if(time.equals(System.getTime()) {
                triggerEvent();
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000); //wait 1 second
    }
}
```

Now this can work ok because i only check time every second which is accurate enough. But i am looking for a more elegant solution like putting the thread to sleep until a certain timer is reached even if it would mean to create another thread.

Is there a more elegant solution than this?

Comment: why don't you use timer framework of java? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you know execution time, you can simply use ScheduledExecutionService

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

To schedule a task:

```
long currentTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
long delayMs = task.getTime() - currentTimeMs;
ses.schedule(eventRunnable, delayMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The benefits of using executor service is that all waiting stuff is implemented under the hood.

Comment: @Gobliins you can't change it, but you can cancel the task and schedule a new one. schedule method returns Future that has cancel method.

Comment: I understand. So i guess, multiple timimgs are also not possible for a single Thread?

Comment: @Gobliins exec service can have as many threads as you wish. you can schedule several tasks to a single service. many things are configurable, I just don't know your requirements, your initial question was simple.